How do I change loot tables to make zombies, skeletons, piglins and creepers drop their heads without needing a charged creeper explosion?
I have downloaded the More Mob Heads data pack by Vanilla Tweaks for Minecraft Java 1.21, as well as their Anti Creeper Grief data pack, which changes Creeper explosions to have an explosion radius of 0. More Mob Heads makes pretty much every mob in the game have a chance to drop their head when killed by a player, but the data pack doesn't include loot tables for zombies, skeletons, piglins and ordinary creepers to drop their heads when killed by a player. As such, I cannot obtain vanilla zombie heads, skeleton skulls, piglin or creeper heads in my world due to all creeper explosions having an explosion radius of 0.
I tried adding .json files to make the 4 mobs have a chance to drop their head when killed by a player, but they never drop their heads no matter what I do.
For creepers, the More Mob Heads data pack does include a .json file for creepers, and it modifies their loot table to allow charged creepers to have a chance to drop a custom charged creeper mob head. I'd like normal creepers to have a chance to drop their heads when killed by a player in addition to charged creepers dropping their own head, but I'm not sure how to do this.
The .json file for creepers is as follows:
{
    "type": "minecraft:entity",
    "pools": [
        {
            "rolls": 1,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "type": "item",
                    "name": "minecraft:player_head",
                    "weight": 1,
                    "functions": [
                        {
                            "function": "set_components",
                            "components": {
                                "minecraft:note_block_sound": "minecraft:entity.generic.explode",
                                "minecraft:profile": {
                                    "properties": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "textures",
                                            "value": "eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvMzUxMWU0YTNkNWFkZDZhNTQ0OTlhYmFkMTBkNzk5ZDA2Y2U0NWNiYTllNTIwYWZkMjAwODYwOGE2Mjg4YjdlNyJ9fX0="
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "minecraft:item_name": "\"Charged Creeper Head\""
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "condition": "killed_by_player"
                },
                {
                    "condition": "entity_properties",
                    "predicate": {
                        "nbt": "{powered:1b}"
                    },
                    "entity": "this"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}


I don't know what you've tried, but you can probably do it like this.
Create JSON files for each of the 4 mobs (except the creeper, which I'll explain) in data/minecraft/loot_tables/entities. You want to put this into the files (replacing zombie with the appropriate mob):
{
  "type": "minecraft:entity",
  "pools": [
    {
      "rolls": 1,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "minecraft:loot_table",
          "value": "vanilla:entities/zombie"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "rolls": 1,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:zombie_head",
          "weight": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

You don't need to worry about creating the loot table vanilla:entities/zombie (and the like), they already exist in the datapack.
As for the creeper, you can replace the existing JSON for the creeper with the following:
{
  "type": "minecraft:entity",
  "pools": [
    {
      "rolls": 1,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "minecraft:loot_table",
          "value": "vanilla:entities/creeper"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "rolls": 1,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "minecraft:loot_table",
          "value": "more_mob_heads:entities/creeper"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "rolls": 1,
      "entries": [{
            "type": "item",
            "name": "minecraft:creeper_head",
            "weight": 1
      }],
      "conditions": [
          {
              "condition": "killed_by_player"
          },
          {
              "condition": "entity_properties",
              "predicate": {
                  "nbt": "{powered:0b}"
              },
              "entity": "this"
          }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Note: None of this is tested.
